# LNK2001 unresolved external symbols

Tags: linker

I am sure this has come up time and time again. I get the following error:

1>precision.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int nprecision"

in my program precision.cxx I have a #include to u.hxx which has the following declaration:

extern int nprecision

Surely this now reads the variable nprecision as an external variable and should all be fine. I am unsure of what is going on.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've done everything I can think of.

Regards

Mat

Comment: You've *declared* `nprecision`, which makes the compiler happy, but you also need to *define* `nprecision` in order to keep the linker happy.

Comment: That makes a LOT of sense. I have to write routines that actually defines/computes them?

Comment: You need to add `int nprecision;` in an implementation file and link that file in with any implementation that references `nprecision`.